# API for Instagram, Facebook, and Twitter

Tags: facebook, api, twitter, instagram

I am looking to build a simple application that could search for specific # in a specific GEO location.

For example:
{#cupcakes #sweets ---- in Dallas TX}

So when a user types in the hashtags only result they will see will be results within 100 miles of desired location. Are there parameters like that within APIs for Instagram, Facebook, and Twitter? Thank you.

Comment: Facebook has no API like that

Answer (score 1):

Check out the twitter [search](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) api:

> Geolocalization: the search operator “near” isn’t available in the API, but there is a more precise way to restrict your query by a given location using the geocode parameter specified with the template “latitude,longitude,radius”, for example, “37.781157,-122.398720,1mi”. When conducting geo searches, the search API will first attempt to find Tweets which have lat/long within the queried geocode, and in case of not having success, it will attempt to find Tweets created by users whose profile location can be reverse geocoded into a lat/long within the queried geocode, meaning that is possible to receive Tweets which do not include lat/long information.